# How to swap values in multiple cells in different column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the values like shown in the example image below. I want to sort all the A cells in a single column and all the B and C cells in a separate respective column. Can any one help with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the data in each row in turn, then open the Sort dialog from Data > Sort, click Options and select "Sort left to right".

Alternatively, just sort the first row, then copy down. There is really no point in trying to sort this data.

Comment: As i mentioned that is an example i have 150 columns and 380 rows of data  in my spreadsheet the above example is my exact situation thanks for you answer

Comment: So, do you have the exact same strings in the 150 columns in all rows, just in a different order of the columns? If you sort row 1, then sort row 2, will both rows then be the same? If they are not the same after sorting, where will they differ? If they differ, please edit your question and provide a data sample that describes your data better. If they don't differ, just copy down and you're done.